# JAVA8 two for each loops to stream

Tags: loops, java-8, java-stream

Hello I have two loops iterating through lists and setting name property using switch, but i want to refactor and use streams instead but not sure how to do it:

here's the code snippet

```
for (ClaimDTO claimDTO: claimDTOs) {
    for (CategoryDTO categoryDTO : claimDTO.getCategories()) {
        switch (categoryDTO.getCategoryType()) {
            case "ALLOWANCE": {
                categoryDTO.setName("Flight");
                break;
            }
            case "MILEAGE": {
                categoryDTO.setyName("Car");
                break;
            }
            default:
                categoryDTO.setName("Expenses");

         }
    }
}
```

Should i create function for resolving name and just use it in stream or it's not even worth and will not save LOC.

Comment: Have you already tried something yourself? This doesn't look like something I'd want to rewrite to streams

Comment: You can avoid the whole nested loops or even streams by making the `name` property of the `CategoryDTO` a calculated property. Or by making the `CategroyDTO` an enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to get all category dtos in a single stream:

```
claimDTOs.stream()
    .flatMap(claim -> claim.getCategories().stream())
    .forEachOrdered(this::setName);
```

[forEachOrdered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) then takes a Consumer which is executed for every element and can be referenced as a method reference (double colons).

```
private void setName(CategoryDTO categoryDTO) {
    switch (categoryDTO.getCategoryType()) {
        case "ALLOWANCE": {
            categoryDTO.setName("Flight");
            break;
        }
        case "MILEAGE": {
            categoryDTO.setName("Car");
            break;
        }
        default:
            categoryDTO.setName("Expenses");

    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `forEach` good enough here? And yes, you rewrote his loops to a stream, but have you gained anything by doing this, e.g. performance, readibility?

Comment: @RobinTopper: If you don't care about ordering (which is probably the case here), yes `forEach` will do. Probably depends on who familiar you are with streams, flatmap, method reference, etc if this is more readable. Personally i find that with streams the code is often more concise and elegant.

Comment: Why did you call stream in flatMap? Doesnt it already return stream?